# Deprecated API com.google.gwt.user.client.Element

Tags: java, dom, gwt

I want substitute GWT deprecated API com.google.gwt.user.client.Element, used for my custom Label.
What is the best way to do this?

```java
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;

public class CustomTabLabel extends Label {

    private String text;

    public CustomTabLabel() {
        super();
        super.setWidth("250px");
    }

    public void setResource(ImageResource imageResource) {
        Image img = new Image(imageResource);
        String definedStyles = img.getElement().getAttribute("style");
        img.getElement().setAttribute("style", definedStyles + "; vertical-align:middle;");
        DOM.insertBefore(getElement(), img.getElement(), DOM.getFirstChild(getElement()));
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        Element span = DOM.createElement("span");
        span.setInnerText(text);
        span.setAttribute("style", "padding-left:7px; padding-right:7px; vertical-align:middle;");

        DOM.insertChild(getElement(), span, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

I'm using 2.6.0 GWT version.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
```

Comment: thats the solution to get rid of the deprecated warning.

Comment: That's solution solve the warning and a bug of "null" and "undefined" in my compiled code.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Element span = Document.get().createSpanElement();
```

For JavaDoc click [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html#createSpanElement%28%29).

Comment: Thanks, I think that this is equivalent to the response of @andrei-volgin.

Comment: How to create a span element that is not deprecated as mentioned by @andrei-volgin?

Comment: I post the entire code because I use some methods that return deprecate Element, so in both cases I obtain the same result. I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hence direct use of Element is deprecated, don't use Element itself, but its subclass SpanElement:

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.SpanElement;

SpanElement span = Document.get().createSpanElement();
DOM.insertChild(getElement(), span, 0);
```